# Jquery Autocomplete - JSON.Parse error

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I'm trying to implement this web api autocomplete in a standard mvc app.
http://techbrij.com/987/jquery-ui-autocomplete-asp-net-web-api

Here's a screen grab from Firebug http://sdrv.ms/N0WkHP
[image]

I've created a controller method and added the jquery script, but I keep getting a 'JSON.parse: unexpected character' error. I don't see any unusual characters in my data.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#txtSearch3').autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/home/Get',
            type: 'GET',
            cache: false,
            data: request,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (json) {
                // call autocomplete callback method with results
                response($.map(json, function (name, val) {
                    return {
                        label: name,
                        value: val
                    }
                }));
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                //alert('error - ' + textStatus);
                console.log('error', textStatus, errorThrown);
            }
        });
    },
    minLength: 2,
    select: function (event, ui) {
        alert('you have selected ' + ui.item.label + ' ID: ' + ui.item.value);
        $('#txtSearch3').val(ui.item.label);
        return false;
    }
})
});
```

// my controller code

```
 public IDictionary<int, string> Get(string term)
    {
        using (myEntities context = new myEntities())

        {
            return context.Categories1.Where(x => x.CategoryName.Contains(term)).ToDictionary(x => x.CategoryId, x => x.CategoryName);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you please post the JSON response you're getting when you post the AJAX request to `/home/Get` ? Also are you sure that the response has this header `Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8` ?

Comment: Hi, my response was System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.Int32,System.String]

After i added Response.ContentType = "application/json";Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8; the reponse never completes.. I see a 'loading' or busy gif all the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, finally figured this out, my return should just have been my valid json, no need for label/value.

Thanks for the helpful replies

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#txtSearch3').autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/home/Get',
            type: 'GET',
            cache: false,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: request,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (json) {

                response($.map(json, function () {
                    return json;

                }));

            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                //alert('error - ' + textStatus);
                console.log('error', textStatus, errorThrown);
            }
        });
    },
    minLength: 2,
    select: function (event, ui) {
        alert('you have selected ' + ui.item.label + ' ID: ' + ui.item.value);
        $('#txtSearch3').val(ui.item.label);
        return false;
    }
})
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Try making your controller return JSON.

```
public JsonResult Get(string term)
{
    using (myEntities context = new myEntities())
    {
        return Json(context.Categories1.Where(x => x.CategoryName.Contains(term)).ToDictionary(x => x.CategoryId, x => x.CategoryName));
    }

}
```

Comment: sorry that didn't work, i get an internal server response, the response header is very long, here's a sample:  <title>Type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]' is not supported for serialization/deserialization of a dictionary, keys must be strings or objects.</title>

Comment: Try `ToList()` instead then unless you need a dictionary for some reason.

Comment: Hi, I.m getting an array of object back now -- [{"label":"Careers","value":"2"},{"label":"Construction / DIY","value":"8"},{"label":"Health","value":"6"},{"label":"Information Technology (IT)","value":"5"},{"label":"Products","value":"25"},{"label":"Property","value":"1"},{"label":"Travel & Holidays","value":"3"},{"label":"Weddings","value":"7"}]
-- but the autocomplete box shows a list of [object Object] entries - can you tell me how to convert that to strings, please? - thanks.